# Rails - How to access the current environment's host URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my rails app for my environments, i have the following:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '0.0.0.0:3000' }
```

How can I access that param in a user_mailer?

I want to get what host equals.

Thanks

Comment: Also, could use help getting either HTTPS or HTTP:// based on the ENV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]
```

Comment: Thanks! that's pretty close to what I was looking for, interestingly it doesn't include HTTP or HTTPS. I use http:// for dev, and https:// for prod. Is there a way to get that in the URL, so I have a full path? thxs!

Comment: Add :protocol, so default_url_options = {:protocol => 'https', :host => 'something.com'}